# Chat for Eclipse IDE in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, chat

I need for a Chat plug-in to be used in Eclipse IDE between developers who work on Eclipse. Is there any available one?

Comment: Why does this need to be an Eclipse plug-in? Can't use IRC or some internal instant messaging client?

Comment: actually I need a chat to let developers contact, and when the chat is closed my system will show a pop-up window asking some questions. I'm not sure if it should be a plug-in or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse Communication Framework has a Jabber client built in ... [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t98659.html) are basic instructions on how to set it up.